# Array/matrix comparison by row instead of column

Tags: r, matrix

I need to compare each item in an array against every element in a matrix. The matrix and array can be any size. I can't use loops or `if` statements - mainly functions like `apply()`, `ifelse()`, and so on. NA data can be ignored. Here is an example:

```
x <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
y <- c(1, NA, 1, NA)
```

The y array needs to compare, in rows, to x - so that after each element in y has compared itself to x, y continues comparing to x as a new row. The solution I want is:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] TRUE NA TRUE NA
[2,] TRUE NA TRUE NA
[3,] FALSE  NA FALSE  NA
```

This function compares with logical equivalence:

```
answer <- function(x,y){
  z <- x == y
  print(z)
}
```

The solution returns the correct answers but in a single row, where the next row should begin after the second `NA`.

```
[1]  TRUE    NA  TRUE    NA  TRUE    NA  TRUE    NA FALSE    NA FALSE    NA
```

When I try to turn that answer into a matrix with column length(y) - 4 in this case - the output isn't correct.

```
answer <- function(x,y){
  z <- x == y
  z2 <- matrix(z, ncol = length(y))
  print(z2)
}
```

The return is comparing values straight down by column:

```
[,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] TRUE   NA  TRUE    NA
[2,]   NA TRUE    NA FALSE
[3,] TRUE   NA FALSE    NA
```

What can I use to make the comparison through each column in a row instead of each row in a column? Can I use `apply(z, 1, some built-in function)` or a nested `apply(apply())` function? The difficulty has been to ensure that the resulting matrix is the correct size, with the correct answer, while compensating for any size array/matrix comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make the lengths same and do the comparison

```
x == y[col(x)]
#       [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  TRUE   NA  TRUE   NA
#[2,] FALSE   NA  TRUE   NA
#[3,]  TRUE   NA FALSE   NA
```

If the comparison is by row

```
x == y
```

Or

```
x== y[row(x)]
```

---

Or with `sweep`

```
sweep(x, 2, y, FUN = `==`)
#       [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  TRUE   NA  TRUE   NA
#[2,] FALSE   NA  TRUE   NA
#[3,]  TRUE   NA FALSE   NA
```

#### data

```
x <- matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1), nrow=3, ncol=4)
y <- c(1, NA, 1, NA)
```

Comment: @user12027316 first column 2nd value is 0 for 'x' while 'y' doesn't have any 0.  If it comparing by row, `x == y`

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
t(t(x) == y)
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  TRUE   NA  TRUE   NA
#[2,] FALSE   NA  TRUE   NA
#[3,]  TRUE   NA FALSE   NA
```

---

```
x <- matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1), nrow=3, ncol=4)
y <- c(1, NA, 1, NA)
```